# How to make tables in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How would I be able to make a table in Unity that displays the date, the character data, and the area of the player like shown in the photo below.. tnx..  [image: character data table]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [Grid Layout Groups](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html) ? ([script](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GridLayoutGroup.html))

Answer (score -2):

You can try to look into some of items on the Asset Store that do that, and either re-use them or study the code.
For examlpe [TSTableView](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/27615)